# How do I create an N-D matrix of doubles in a MATLAB MEX file?

Tags: matlab, matrix, mex

I need to make a 3-D matrix in a MEX file. In the API reference, there is mention of `mxCreateCellArray` for N-D cell arrays, `mxCreateStructArray` for structs, etc. But there is no `mxCreateDoubleArray` mentioned. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`mxCreateNumericArray`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/apiref/mxcreatenumericarray.html) to create arrays of different types by specifying the appropriate array class identifier for the `classid` argument:

- **C syntax:** use `mxDOUBLE_CLASS` for the `classid` argument.
- **Fortran syntax:** use the function [`mxClassIDFromClassName`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/apiref/mxclassidfromclassname.html) with the argument `'double'` to get the value for the `classid` argument.